# Utility for string searches on remote server

Tags: windows, linux, remote-access, web-server

I need a utility that I can run on my Windows 7 PC, that will give me the capability to do string searches on ASCII files (HTML, SHTML, CSS, JS, etc.) residing on a REMOTE Linux/Apache server. Reason being: I'm administrating for a department and need to find, for example, all of the files that have a specific CSS file linked in. I can't do this w/ Dreamweaver or Filezilla, which I've always used for development work. Now I need an admin tool. Can anybody reco a utility that would allow me to do that?

**Note**: I do have FTP access to the server for sure. Not sure about SSH, as I'm not much of a network guy - more a designer. They had me install "Pulse" for the VPN connection. I would expect not to have too much power, as I'm a developer not an admin. That's what kind of complicates this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a remote shell such as a ssh or telnet client for windows, there are lots including telnet from the command line and them there are lots of ways of searching on Linux such as find + grep or a python script.

You could even install python on your windows machine and use it to automate the whole process of doing a remote login and the search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only FTP, then the sad truth is that you can not perform searches remotely.

You will have to download everything locally and search locally.

*There might be programs that help with this particular operation (for instance searching files in memory just after download, without saving files to the disk), but I don't know any.*